# Sometimes latin alphabet (ä ö ü è ß) characters are returned as �

Tags: node.js, unicode

I want to return in response the orginal text.

But when I have the letter ä, I'm sometimes getting �� instead.

e.g. for Stäblistraße, The cloud returns St��blistraße.
It's not always happened. But even one time is too much..

How can I verify it will never happened again?

I tried `utf8.decode(value)` But not working - `Error: Invalid continuation byte`.

Attached code snippet:

```
var sendResponse = function(res,response,type)
{
  res.writeHeader(200, {
    "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
  });
  res.write((JSON.stringify(response))+"\n");
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant details and code. Where are you reading from? How are you printing these values?

Comment: I'm reading the values from solr

Comment: Cloud is node.js server.

Comment: You don't talk about encodings at all, without mentioning an encoding, characters like ä don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting valid UTF-8 already in `St��blistraße`, since the `ä` is rendered as two bytes. However, your browser doesn't know it's UTF-8. Either send the header (probably using `response.setHeader()`):

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

or include a `meta` tag in your HTML:

- In HTML5,

  ```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ```
- In HTML4/XHTML,

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ```

(Assuming you're sending HTML to a browser; you are a bit vague on the details).

Answer (score 0):

To output the value try use the coressponding entities

```
ä =  &auml;
ö =   &ouml;
ü =   &uuml;
ß =   &szlig;
eg Stäblistraße,  will be St&auml;blistra&szlig;e,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myText = new Buffer('Stäblistraß', 'utf8')
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' });
res.write(encodeURIComponent.myText.toString('utf8'));
```

On the browser end, use `decodeURIComponent()` to convert string back. Works every time.

Comment: sending the header shouldn't be enough?

Comment: With Asian fonts problem gets worse, even with correct header. Either base64.encode() or [encodeUriComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) fixes this issue.